# elasticsearch on python gives name or service not known

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm working with an elastic API on a url like https://something.xyzw.eg/api/search/advance **(not the real url)**. The API works fine on postman. Also the python code generated by postman works fine and returns results. However when using [leasticsearch-dsl package](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/docs/index.rst) I keep getting:

> Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)

Here is my code similar to the [first example on documents](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.16.3/#example-usage):

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

client = Elasticsearch(host='https://something.xyzw.eg/api/search/advance')
s = Search(using=client)    
response = s.execute()
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

**Edit:**

Apparently `host` shouldn't contain a url, but a hostname. However, I don't have any control on where the API is. Is there a workaround to get `elasticsearch` to work with url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference: it turned out that the API I was using wasn't in fact the standard ElasticSearch, but would proxy my request to the ElasticSearch. So sending requests by postman and `requests` package would work (as the requsets were sent to Elastic), but `elasticsearch-py` couldn't connect to it (since the route I was trying to connect to wasn't actually Elastic itself).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add `port=443` as in one of the examples from the doc you mentioned https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.16.3/#tls-ssl-and-authentication ?